# Can someone help me modify a script that creates an enemy's vision in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing my first platform game in Unity. Right now, I'm working on the AI for enemies that will chase the player. I'd like to modify the following script so that the player is detected as soon as they enter the field of view. Currently, it uses the transform so that only when the center of the character is in the angle is the player detected.

csharp

```
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // If outside visionRange, return false
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > visionRange)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Vector2 toTarget = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    Vector2 visionDirection = GetVisionDirection();

    if (Vector2.Angle(visionDirection, toTarget) > visionAngle / 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // TODO: Check for objects obstructing vision
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the code for detecting any obstacles obstructing the vision? If that so, you can use Raycasts!

```cs
{
    ...

    if (Vector2.Angle(visionDirection, toTarget) > visionAngle / 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
    if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TrasnformDirection(visionDirection), out hit, visionRange, layerMaskOfThePlayer))
        {

           return false;
        }

    return true;
}
```

This just directs a ray directly in the direction of player, and if it hits anything other than the player (defined by the playerLayerMask), it returns false, since it means something's in between!

References: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Answer (score 0):

To check for objects obstructing vision, you can use raycasting. Raycasting allows you to cast rays from your enemy's position in the direction of vision and check if these rays hit any obstacles. If a ray hits an object, you can determine if it is between the enemy and the player, thus obstructing the vision.

```
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // If outside visionRange, return false
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > visionRange)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Vector2 toTarget = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    Vector2 visionDirection = GetVisionDirection();

    if (Vector2.Angle(visionDirection, toTarget) > visionAngle / 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Raycast to check for objects obstructing vision
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, toTarget, visionRange);

    if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.CompareTag("ObstacleVision"))
    {
        // If the raycast hits an object tagged as "ObstacleVision," return false
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Make sure to set the tags of the objects you want to consider as vision obstacles. In the code above, I used "ObstacleVision" as an example tag, but you'll need to adapt it based on your objects.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to modify the script so that the player is detected as soon as they enter the field of view, you can change the conditions based on the dot product of vectors. This allows you to detect the relative direction of the target from the enemy's forward direction. Here's an example of a script that would work:

```
{
if (target == null)
{
    return false;
}

// If outside visionRange, return false
if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > visionRange)
{
    return false;
}

Vector2 toTarget = target.transform.position - transform.position;
Vector2 visionDirection = GetVisionDirection();

// Calculate the dot product
float dotProduct = Vector2.Dot(visionDirection.normalized, toTarget.normalized);

// Check if the dot product is greater than a certain threshold
// This threshold determines how strict the line of sight is
float dotThreshold = Mathf.Cos(visionAngle / 2 * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

if (dotProduct > dotThreshold)
{
    // TODO: Check for objects obstructing vision
    return true;
}

return false;
```

}